# calling Elixir method using shell script

Tags: elixir

```
defmodule MyModule do
   def print do
        IO.puts "hi all"
    end
end
```

This is my Elixir module contained in MyModule.erl

```
iex MyModule.erl
MyModule.print
```

I was trying to run the elixir method using a shell script. It compiles the file but

```
iex MyModule.erl
```

is not running. I think it's because the first command goes to Erlang virtual machine. How to call this method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Elixir files generally have .ex extension. And if you are not planning to compile it, we recommend using the .exs file. We cover those differences in [our getting started guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/1.html).

Assuming you write the file above to "mod.exs", one of the ways to achieve what you want is:

```
elixir -r mod.exs -e "MyModule.print"
```